# How to xargs multiple string arguments to one command

Tags: shell, arguments

like this:

```
echo $USER $PASSWORD $RESOURCE_MACHINE $SELECT_SQL  $TARGET_MACHINE $INSERT_SQL | xargs -n6 bash -c '/usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u $1 --password $2 -h $3 -q $4 | /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u $1 --password $2 -h $5 -q $6' bash
```

Every argument is a string.

Comment: Do you mean something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623391/4970442)?

Comment: What's the use of `xargs` in this example? Are you going to have further sets of parameters than the one you're passing with `echo`?  Note that you _really_ need to double quote all variable expansions to avoid word splitting and filename globbing, both for the `echo` and inside you in-line script. Do any of your values potentially contain spaces or newlines?

Comment: I think you have problem because content of your variable may be have space, for solving it , set IFS variable.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs`' input needs to be formatted in a very specific format. The strings that are to become arguments need to be separated with SPC, TAB, NL (and possibly other whitespace character depending on the `xargs` implementation and locale), and if any of those characters may occur in the strings, they need to be quoted with single quotes, double quotes or backslash (except for NL that can only be escaped with backslash).

backslash and quotes also need to  be escaped. And empty elements have to be enclosed in quotes so as not to be discarded.

So here, you can't use `echo` to output the list of words in the format recognised by `xargs`. More generally, `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data anyway as it does its own processing of backslashes and/or leading arguments starting with `-`.

Here, with `bash`, you could define:

```
print-for-xargs() {
  local nl=$'\n'
  if (($# > 0)); then
    set -- "${@//\'/\'\\\'\'}"
    printf "'%s'\n" "${@//$nl/\'\\$nl\'}"
  fi
}
```

That function prints its arguments in the format expected by `xargs` (putting each argument inside single quotes, with single quotes and newlines themselves quoted with backslash *outside* of the single-quoted strings).

Then, you can do:

```
print-for-xargs "$USER" \
                "$PASSWORD" \
                "$RESOURCE_MACHINE" \
                "$SELECT_SQL" \
                "$TARGET_MACHINE" \
                "$INSERT_SQL" |
  xargs -n6 bash -c '
    /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u "$1" --password "$2" -h "$3" -q "$4" |
      /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u "$1" --password "$2" -h "$5" -q "$6"
    ' bash
```

Also remember that parameter expansions have to be quoted in `bash` like in most other POSIX-like shells.

If your `xargs` supports the non-standard `-0` option (for NUL-delimited records on input, 0 being the only only byte value that cannot occur in a command arguments), that can be greatly simplified to:

```
print_for_xargs0() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"
}
print_for_xargs0 "$USER" \
                 "$PASSWORD" \
                 "$RESOURCE_MACHINE" \
                 "$SELECT_SQL" \
                 "$TARGET_MACHINE" \
                 "$INSERT_SQL" |
  xargs -0 -n6 sh -c '
    /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u "$1" --password "$2" -h "$3" -q "$4" |
      /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u "$1" --password "$2" -h "$5" -q "$6"
    ' sh
```

(no need for `bash` there, standard `sh` will do as well)

That's assuming you do need to call `xargs` for some reason and that you're just showing a simplified example.

Here, you could just do:

```
  bash -c '
    /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u "$1" --password "$2" -h "$3" -q "$4" |
      /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u "$1" --password "$2" -h "$5" -q "$6"
    ' bash "$USER" "$PASSWORD" "$RESOURCE_MACHINE" "$SELECT_SQL" \
           "$TARGET_MACHINE" "$INSERT_SQL"
```

without invoking `xargs` at all or:

```
/usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u "$USER" --password "$PASSWORD" \
   -h "$RESOURCE_MACHINE" -q "$SELECT_SQL" |
   /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u "$USER" --password "$PASSWORD" \
   -h "$TARGET_MACHINE" -q "$INSERT_SQL"
```

without running a separate instance of a `bash` interpreter.

Also note that in all those examples, the value of `$PASSWORD` ends up in the arguments passed to `clickhouse-client` (and `bash` for those that run `bash`) which is bad practice as command arguments are public knowledge locally on a system (they show in the output of  `ps -f` and could end up in audit logs).

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use GNU Parallel:

```
echo "$USER $PASSWORD $RESOURCE_MACHINE $SELECT_SQL $TARGET_MACHINE $INSERT_SQL" |
  parallel --colsep ' ' /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u {1} --password {2} -h {3} -q {4} '|' /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u {1} --password {2} -h {5} -q {6}
```

We assume that there is no space in the variables.

If you have spaces in the variables, select a string which does not appear (e.g. :::) and use that:

```
echo "$USER:::$PASSWORD:::$RESOURCE_MACHINE:::$SELECT_SQL $TARGET_MACHINE:::$INSERT_SQL" |
  parallel --colsep ':::' /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u {1} --password {2} -h {3} -q {4} '|' /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u {1} --password {2} -h {5} -q {6}
```

In your particular case, though, it seems redundant, as you can use the variables directly in the command.

```
/usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u "$USER" --password "$PASSWORD" -h "$RESOURCE_MACHINE" -q "$SELECT_SQL" |
  /usr/bin/clickhouse-client -u "$USER" --password "$PASSWORD" -h "$TARGET_MACHINE" -q "$INSERT_SQL"
```

Comment: If there was *no space in the variables*, the OP's approach would have likely worked. Things like `$SELECT_SQL` sound likely to contain space.